# Is Tamarind String Edible?

Tags: food-safety, tamarind

Today at lunch, i accidentally ate a small piece of tamarind string. I am not sure whether it would be digested inside my body. I am little worried. Can someone tell if i am going to be safe, or would there be any side effects ?

[image: Tamarind string]

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question appears to be more of a health-related question than cooking/food related. You may not find a satisfactory answer here. However, if you only swallowed a small amount I don't think there is anything to worry about. The whole pod, including seeds, is non-toxic, and it is unlikely to do any 'mechanical' damage to you